# How to assign specific line from another file to a variable in bash

Tags: bash

I have another file that has 2 numerical values...

`22`

`35`

I want to read those values and assign each to a variable.

There will only ever be two values, so a loop shouldn't be necessary.

I found ways to get the value line by line, but I'm unsure how to save those values to a variable that I can use in my main script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way to read two lines in succession is:

```
{ read var1 ; read var2 ; } <data
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
read a b < <(egrep -o '[0-9]+' file|tr '\n' ' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash 4, you can read the lines into an array

```
mapfile -t numbers < file
echo ${numbers[0]} ${numbers[1]}
```